# How to get breeze-gtk on Centos8 / EPEL?

Tags: centos

I installed KDE on Centos 8 but I can't find breeze-gtk in EPEL for Centos 8:
https://pkgs.org/search/?q=breeze-gtk 
It seems to me like the EPEL maintainers simply forgot to include it.

Is there a simple workaround to install it on Centos 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [download the tarball](https://download.kde.org/stable/plasma/5.23.2/breeze-gtk-5.23.2.tar.xz) and install it manually. Installation instructions from the README look very simple:

> If your distribution doesn't provide a package, you can install the theme system-wide by copying it to the appropriate directory, usually "/usr/share/themes".
>
> ```
> find Breeze* -type f -exec install -Dm644 '{}' "$pkgdir/usr/share/themes/{}" \;
> ```
>
> To install only for the current user, copy the files to "~/.themes".

You can also [ask for the package to be included in EPEL](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/epel/fedora-package-in-epel/).